# Delete all characters before 1-3 digits and string - r and regex

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I need to extract the mg quantity from data that looks like this:

```
(100) x 10mg zepose valium ..(cipla in strips)
-- 20x2mg -- diclazepam
(10) clonazepam 2mg / roche rivotril 
...
```

In R, I use this regex to remove all text after "mg":

```
dataset$quantity <- gsub('mg.+?$','mg',dataset$quantity)
```

The output is like this:

```
(100) x 10mg
-- 20x2mg
(10) clonazepam 2mg
```

How can I remove the text before 'mg' while also keeping the quantity? The range is from 1mg to 200mg, so from single to three digits.

Sometimes there's whitespace immediately before the mg digit(s), but not always. One pattern, however, is that there's never a number immediately before the mg quantity (unless separated by whitespace).

Based on my limited understanding of regex I'm thus looking for a code that can **delete all characters before 1-3 digits and 'mg'**. I've looked around and can't find what I need.

Edit:

My desired output is:

```
10mg
2mg
2mg
```

Please ignore that the text refers to 1000mg (100 x 10mg), 40mg (20 x 2mg) etc. I will have to do those calculations by hand I think.

Comment: It's not very clear what is your desired output. Do you want for example `(100) x 10mg` or just `10mg`? Can you provide a desired output in your question?

Comment: If the numbers can be both float and int, use [`sub('.*?(\\d[0-9.]*\\s*mg).*','\\1',x)`](https://ideone.com/Wyv2m0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) sub** Match everything before 1-3 digits followed by mg followed by anything else and replace that with the match to the capture group (parenthesized portion) consisting of the digits and mg:

```
dat <- c("(100) x 10mg zepose valium ..(cipla in strips)", 
"-- 20x2mg -- diclazepam",
"(10) clonazepam 2mg / roche rivotril")

sub(".*?(\\d{1,3}mg).*", "\\1", dat)
## [1] "10mg" "2mg"  "2mg"
```

If you don't want to return the `mg` part then put the right parenthesis before mg instead of after it.

**2) strcapture** Another possibility is

```
strcapture("(\\d{1,3}mg)", dat, data.frame(mg = character(0)))
```

giving this data frame:

```
    mg
1 10mg
2  2mg
3  2mg
```

**Update:** There was an update to the question regarding calculating the quantity times the mg:

```
DF <- strcapture("(\\d+)\\D+(\\d+)", dat, data.frame(qty = numeric(0), mg = numeric(0)))
transform(DF, total = qty * mg, desc = sub(".*mg *", "", dat))
```

giving:

```
  qty mg total                              desc
1 100 10  1000 zepose valium ..(cipla in strips)
2  20  2    40                     -- diclazepam
3  10  2    20                  / roche rivotril
```

Comment: Thanks you this worked. For others who might be looking, I did this with gsub: dataset$quantity <- gsub(".*?(\\d{1,4}mg).*", "\\1", dataset$quantity)

Comment: Have added update regarding returning the quantity * mg

Answer (score 2):

With `gsub`/`sub` (Doesn't matter which one in this case since you only have one `mg` per row):

```
dataset$quantity <- gsub('.+?(\\d+\\s?mg).+', '\\1', dataset$quantity)
```

or with `str_extract` from `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
dataset$quantity = str_extract(dataset$quantity, "\\d+\\s?mg")
```

**Result:**

```
  quantity
1     10mg
2      2mg
3      2mg
```

**Notes:**

1. `.+?` matches any character one or more time lazily.
2. `(\\d+\\s?mg)` is a capture group that matches a digit one or more times followed by a space zero or one times followed by the literal `"mg"`.
3. `\\1` in `gsub`/`sub` replaces the pattern with whatever is in the first capture group, in this case `(\\d+\\s?mg)`. So the `gsub`/`sub` solution effectively removes everything except `<digits>[space]mg`.
4. `str_extract` is a different approach, which extracts a pattern, instead of replacing. In this case, I am extracting `\\d+\\s?mg` directly.

**Data:**

```
dataset = structure(list(quantity = c("(100) x 10mg zepose valium ..(cipla in strips)", 
"-- 20x2mg -- diclazepam", "(10) clonazepam 2mg / roche rivotril"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L), .Names = "quantity")
```